# Naming conventions in pgAdmin3

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am creating tables in the GUI of postgreSQL, PgAdmin3. There is an element that seems to be specious in the naming of the tables. The following is my fragmented comprehension of postgreSQL (I could be wrong if I am, please rectify). I am inserting tables in the database using the ETL tool Talend.

When there is only one schema in the database: No reference to the schema is mandatory

```
       select * from tablename
```

When there is more than one schema in the database: Reference to the schema is mandatory and the reference to the schema is required in quotes

```
       select * from "schema".tablename
```

There is something new I drifted upon yesterday and I do not know what might be causing pgAdmin to do this:

```
       select * from "schema"."tablename"
```

I am not oblivious of the part that referencing to the specific schema is mandatory when there is more than one schema present in the same database and in quotes but why does one need to have the table name in quotes as well.

Comment: `but why does one need to have the table name in quotes as well.` In short: You don't. (only when the names contain uppercase letters or strange characters)

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS